# Text and figure overlapping using flowfram

Tags: graphics, report, flowfram

I use the flowfram package to compile my brochure. I want to use the staticcontents to add a picture on page 6, which somehow overlaps with the text on the same page. How could I solve this problem? I leave some text out in the code for simplicity.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{flowfram}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\onecolumninarea[1]{0.6\textwidth}{\textheight}{0.4\textwidth}{0pt}
\onecolumnStopinarea[>1]{0.1\textheight}{0.6\textwidth}{\textheight}{0.4\textwidth}{0pt}

\newstaticframe[6]{0.8\textwidth}{.4\textheight}{0.2\textwidth}{0.6\textheight}[statico]


\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

The unanticipated epidemic outbreak of COVID-19 enforces many governments to adopt confinement policy, leading to a huge froze of economic activities. Except for the gigantic decrease in consumption, many non-essential industries also suffer from stagnation of production. Among reasons such as demand shocks and supply chain disruption, a new concern regarding the productivity of working from home (WFH) during the pandemic period comes into sight. This topic catches much attention not only because many discussants are, at the same time, now "remote-workers" but also due to the uncertain ending time of WFH. In this short article, I will try to give an academic discussion of the WFH efficiency issue.

\begin{staticcontents*}{statico}
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textheight,height=0.4\textheight]{Figure_2.jpg}
\end{staticcontents*}


\section*{WFH efficiency and GDP}

While many recent working papers provide lights on one factor, the capital, that impact the forecast of GDP, I shall bring about interesting points on total factor productivity. Generally we believe the revolution of productivity is slow and steady during a short period, and technology innovations, such as electricity, the Internet, and AI, positively promote product development speed. The flourishing of modern science and technology has lasted for over a century, making people hard to imagine we may face a productivity decrease due to a pandemic.\\
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I can't figure out where you are trying to put things.  Your widths and heights are inconsistent and don't add up.  The most important thing is that the x,y locations are given relative to the lower left corner of the text areas, so the x location plus the width should be less than \textwidth and the height plus the y locatoon should be less than \textheight (to fit into the text area).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've edited my question again. I want to put the image at the top-right corner of the page6 and the text will follow that image.  The text is still overlapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frames normally overlap, unless specifically set to not overlap.

I don't have any experience with `\onecolumninarea` etc.  If I need two columns on a page, I just use two flow frames.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{flowfram}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newflowframe[1]{0.6\textwidth}{0.6\textheight}{0.4\textwidth}{0pt}
\newflowframe[>1]{0.6\textwidth}{\textheight}{0.4\textwidth}{0pt}

\newstaticframe[1]{0.8\textwidth}{.4\textheight}{0.2\textwidth}{0.6\textheight}[statico]

\begin{staticcontents*}{statico}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=0.4\textheight]{example-image}
\end{staticcontents*}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

The unanticipated epidemic outbreak of COVID-19 enforces many governments to adopt confinement policy, leading to a huge froze of economic activities. Except for the gigantic decrease in consumption, many non-essential industries also suffer from stagnation of production. Among reasons such as demand shocks and supply chain disruption, a new concern regarding the productivity of working from home (WFH) during the pandemic period comes into sight. This topic catches much attention not only because many discussants are, at the same time, now "remote-workers" but also due to the uncertain ending time of WFH. In this short article, I will try to give an academic discussion of the WFH efficiency issue.



\section*{WFH efficiency and GDP}

While many recent working papers provide lights on one factor, the capital, that impact the forecast of GDP, I shall bring about interesting points on total factor productivity. Generally we believe the revolution of productivity is slow and steady during a short period, and technology innovations, such as electricity, the Internet, and AI, positively promote product development speed. The flourishing of modern science and technology has lasted for over a century, making people hard to imagine we may face a productivity decrease due to a pandemic.\\
\end{document}
```

Comment: I now add a special `\newflowframe` to the page6, to let the text starts just below the figure. I find out the overlapping problem is due to the conflict of my `\onecolumnStopinarea` and the `\newstaticframe` commands. Thanks.